# Find optimal figure size to fit two images on one page

Tags: graphics, floats, scaling, automation

I often encounter a situation where I would like to fit two or three figures on one page.
I define my figures as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]     
\centering       
\includegraphics[width=0.xx\linewidth]{images/filename.png}     
\caption{Caption}   
\label{fig:tag}      
\end{figure}
```

The `xx` value depends on the size of the image I'm using and it takes some trial and error to find the optimal value. With square graphs `xx=50` approximately.

I am looking for a way to avoid the trial and error part. I assume I need to use something else than `\linewidth`, but I don't know what.

**Updates:**

I've tried `0.5\pageheight` instead of `\linewidth` but this is not satisfactory. I can fit two images on one page even if I use `0.6\pageheight` for the size of each image. This is in *landscape* mode though. 
This is not logical to me as that would mean the two images together would span 1.2 times the height of the page.

I've also tried to set my height of the image in *portrait* mode just to test. I've set `height=0.5\textheight` and `height=0.5\paperheight` but both generate images that are too large to fit together on one page.

Comment: If it is the height not the width that is the limiting factor you want height= not width= or you can specify both and use `keepaspectratio` so that it does not distort the image.

Comment: did you use `0.6\pageheight` for the `width` or the `height`?

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that I was in a `landscape` environment. But I just tried `height=0.5\paperheight` and `height=0.5\textheight` in normal portrait mode but both give images that don't fit on one page together. I've edited the **Updates** section to reflect my experiences.

Comment: keep in mind that the caption needs some space too. But even without the figure environment I need something like `height=0.5\textheight` and `height=0.495\textheight` to put two images on one page - cause there is a gap of 0.1em between the images.

Comment: Yes, I know the captions need some space, but I was hoping there would be some command which just places two images, including captions, on one page without fiddling to find the correct size.

Comment: What do you think about defining a new float environment (for example, `doublefigure`) which looks like the standard `figure` but with some different vertical spaces. You can define it with 2 mandatory arguments and set the correct space between them, also above and below the environment. This is only a suggestion even I don't know if it'll work.

Comment: A crucial piece of information is: Do the images included in the `figure` environments all have the same natural heights and widths? If not, is it OK to make them all the same size? If it's not OK to force them to have the same height and/or width, how should one proceed?

Comment: @Mico: For simplicity it can be assumed that the images have the same height and width. That is the case 90% of the time for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following example assumes that the images can be scaled to the half of the text height,
then the example measures the height of the captions and calculates the available height for the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\newsavebox\CaptionBoxA
\newsavebox\CaptionBoxB
\newlength\ImgHeight   

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \vbox to \textheight{%
    \centering
    \setbox\CaptionBoxA=\vbox{%
      \begingroup % color support
        \centering
        \caption{My first figure}%
        \label{fig:first}%
      \endgroup
    }
    \setbox\CaptionBoxB=\vbox{%
      \begingroup % color support
        \centering
        \caption{My second figure}%
        \label{fig:second}%
      \endgroup
    }
    \setlength{\ImgHeight}{%
      .5\dimexpr\textheight 
        -\ht\CaptionBoxA-\dp\CaptionBoxA
        -\ht\CaptionBoxB-\dp\CaptionBoxB
        -\floatsep
      \relax
    }

    \rule{10mm}{\ImgHeight}%
    % \includegraphics[height=\ImgHeight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{...}

    \unvbox\CaptionBoxA

    \vspace{\floatsep}
    \vspace{0pt minus .25\floatsep}% glue for safety
    \vspace{0pt plus 1fil}% glue for smaller images 
    \nointerlineskip % interline skip affects the calculation of \ImgHeight

    \rule{10mm}{\ImgHeight}
    % \includegraphics[height=\ImgHeight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{...}

    \unvbox\CaptionBoxB
    % \vspace{0pt plus 1fil}% glue for smaller images
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result with paper size A5 and rules instead of images:

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- The code would have to be put in a macro for practical usage.
- There is room for improvements. For example, the available space is
  equally distributed among the images. If one image cannot be scaled to the
  available space because of width limitations, then the other image could grow.
- There is room for extensions (three and more images, ...).

Comment: works great and there's room for tweaking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After running it a couple of times I noticed LaTeX chokes on `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}`. It says: Option clash for package geometry. If I delete the arguments I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: @BartArondson The `\usepackage[pass,showframe]` was just added for _showing_ the page layout. Thus you do not need it for your real world file. If you want to see the page layout, just add `showframe` to your option list of `geometry` or use `\PassOptionsToPackage{showframe}{geometry}` right at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I think that @Heiko Oberdiek's answer is way more *pro* than mine. These are just a couple tricks. I'm not even sure *why*, but so far, these seem to work for me.

Maybe this answer is not even very TeX-like, but I'm a graphic designer with some experience, and just based on sheer amount of trial and error routines in the past, I am now accustomed to get two/three figures per page (or more) using a size of 45% the text height for two vertical images, or 45% the text  width, for the horizontal ones. Use 30% for three images, etc. The trick is always leave around 10% of the `\textwhatever` free. It also helps a lot placing figures inside minipages, see this example (adapted to latex from other examples found in the LyX Wiki):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Remember that line breaks matter. 
\begin{document}
% this some image i have, use your own...
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\\
[0.25cm]

\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}\\
[0.25cm]\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

Several images in one page.%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}\\
[0.25cm]\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\\
[0.25cm]

\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.3\columnwidth}%
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/_orig/c2/c2-img2}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am looking more for a "pro" solution, so thanks for your effort, but Heiko Oberdiek did a better job.