# Placing two figures (each having subfigures) next two each other

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I would like to place two figures, where each `figure` has subfigures next to each other. 
I tried with `minipage`, but tex does not like the `\subfigure` as `Not in outer par mode`.
Is there any way to place figures with subfigures next to each other?

```
\begin{figure*}[htbp]


\begin{minipage}[hbt]{0,49\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Subfigure 1.1]{
\label{fig:subfig1_1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.42]{graphs/sub_1_1.pdf}
}

\subfigure[Sub 1.2] {
\label{fig:subfig1_2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.42]{graphs/sub_1_2.pdf}
}
}
\label{fig:subfigure1} 
\caption{Subfigure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}




\begin{minipage}[hbt]{0,49\textwidth}
%... as above
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please change your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your document class and relevant packages.

Comment: Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76153/find-optimal-figure-size-to-fit-two-images-on-one-page

Answer (score 4):

You can't put a floating object inside a `minipage`, but you can place `minipage`s inside a floating object. I notice that you are using the obsolete `subfigure` package; you should use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Below there are two approaches; the first one using the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package, and the other one using the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} % Needs subfig for this example.

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2}}
\caption{First figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig3}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig4}}
\caption{Second figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2}}
\caption{First figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig3}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig4}}
\caption{Second figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: +1 what is the pros and cons betweem both approaches?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ  [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/3954) and its answers give a good comparison.

Comment: @Speravir yes it was a typo. I had `subcaption` in both examples (the problems of copy-paste).

Answer (score 2):

Since `figure` is a floating object and `minipage`s are not, you can't use `figure`s inside `minipage`s. One method is to avoid using `figure` and use the `captionof` from `caption`/`subcation` (or `capt-of`) package.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\captionof{subfigure}{sub figure - 1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\captionof{subfigure}{sub figure - 2} 
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{figure one}
\end{minipage}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
\captionof{subfigure}{sub figure - 1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{subfigure}{sub figure - 2}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{figure two}
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not appropriate to use `hbt` in the optional argument of `minipage` (you can use `t`, `b`, or `c`).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina My bad. I copied it as such from the OP's code and overlooked. Thanks for noting.

Comment: +1 Harish :) have you tried cross referencing a `subfigure` using this method? It produces the incorrect numbers--yikes!

Comment: @cmhughes: No Chris. but I will do today after dome time. :-)