# How to order 3 images horizontally (two with sub-figure and the third one is one figure)

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

I put three figures in a row. One figure is independent one and with a caption underneath; the other two figures are sub-figures. Please see the picture below.

[image]

I tried to combine `minipage` with `subfigure`, but it didn't work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78760/placing-two-figures-each-having-subfigures-next-two-each-other?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is first figure}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{example-image}}  
  \caption{caption}
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And an option using `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\quad
\subfloat[subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I tried to run this code, it cannot find subcaption.sty

Comment: @HarishKumar I added another option to your answer, using subfig. I hope you don't mind (it's the first time I do this, so please excuse me if I was too intruding, but a separate answer seemed superfluous). If you don't like the edit, please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @minmin please see the updated answer for a solution using subfig.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You are always welcome. Please feel free to edit/modify my answers always :-). You are very kind.

Comment: @minmin You're welcome! The hard work was done by Harish. If you consider the answer solved your problem, don't forget that you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubt please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).