# combining two different graphs in a single pgfplot in LaTex

Tags: pgfplots, sharelatex

I have this two graphs made with pgfplot in ShareLaTex, my advisor wants me to show them in a single graph, the two plots will be recognized by solid and dashed lines respectively. also the legend will define which plot stands for p=0 and which for p=1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
Case I : $p=0$ and $n=0$ 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title={ Energy density $\rho$},
xlabel={r/R},
    ylabel={$\frac{\kappa}{C} \rho$},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.2,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}]

\addplot[
    color=blue]
    coordinates {
    (0,8.71)(0.1,8.61)(0.2,8.33)(0.3,7.90)(0.4,7.35)(0.5,6.73)(0.6,6.08)(0.7,5.42)(0.8,4.78)(0.9,4.18)(1,3.61)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello world}\label{fig:myplot}
\end{figure}


Case II : $ p=1$ and $n=0$

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title={ Energy density $\rho$},
xlabel={r/R},
    ylabel={$\frac{\kappa}{C} \rho$},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.2,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}]

\addplot[
    color=blue]
    coordinates {
    (0,9.3725549039
)(0.1,9.3285550312
)(0.2,9.1985115839
)(0.3,8.9879707942
)(0.4,8.7051855159
)(0.5,8.3598886397
)(0.6,7.9619965855
)(0.7,7.5204841058
)(0.8,7.0425813594
)(0.9,6.5333394278
)(1,5.9955267351
)};

 \\   
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "central" part of your code, the one that stops one axis and starts the second one. Then you can easily add the legend using the `\legend` command.

In the axis options you'll find some keys for customising your legend.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title={ Energy density $\rho$},
xlabel={r/R},
    ylabel={$\frac{\kappa}{C} \rho$},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.2,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    legend style={
        cells={anchor=west},
        draw=none, fill=none, 
        font=\scriptsize,
        legend pos= south west,
    }]

\addplot[
    color=blue]
    coordinates {
    (0,8.71)(0.1,8.61)(0.2,8.33)(0.3,7.90)(0.4,7.35)(0.5,6.73)(0.6,6.08)(0.7,5.42)(0.8,4.78)(0.9,4.18)(1,3.61)
    };

\addplot[
    color=blue, dashed]
    coordinates {
    (0,9.3725549039
)(0.1,9.3285550312
)(0.2,9.1985115839
)(0.3,8.9879707942
)(0.4,8.7051855159
)(0.5,8.3598886397
)(0.6,7.9619965855
)(0.7,7.5204841058
)(0.8,7.0425813594
)(0.9,6.5333394278
)(1,5.9955267351
)};

\legend{Case I: $p=0$ and $n=0$, Case II: $p=1$ and $n=0$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My combined plot}\label{fig:combined}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I need one more info. When I try to copy this code and insert other coordinates for different plot, why does not it compile? I need to put other 6 plots just below this graph, but for some resons, latex only compiles this particular plot, any idea why?

Comment: @tazkerahaque Uhm that's weird. Give me one plot here in the comments as an example. I mean, the coordinates and so on.

Comment: sorry , I add the code in the form of an answer, can you please check it? thanks

Comment: @tazkerahaque It works for me. Check the next pages. You can even combine the plots in this code.

Comment: yes that's my problem , I want it in a single page, to be precise, I need two plots per page

Comment: @tazkerahaque See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77945/4778). Does it help you?

Comment: @tazkerahaque Please delete your other answer (since it's not actually an answer). And glad it helped! :D